# Jalo layer generate different class names

Tags: java, ant, sap-commerce-cloud

I have this project hierarchy, with `jalo` class highlighted in blue:

[image][image]

To overwrite `jalo` class I do

```
<itemtype code="RgBrandRestriction" extends="AbstractRestriction" autocreate="true" generate="true" jaloclass="com.***.customjalo.RgBrandRestriction">
```

and get generated class

```
public abstract class GeneratedRgBrandRestriction
```

then overwrite it by my custom class

```
public class RgBrandRestriction extends GeneratedRgBrandRestriction
```

but, when I do `<itemtype code="RgCronJob" extends="CronJob" autocreate="true" generate="true" jaloclass="com.***.core.customjalo.cronjob.RgCronJob">`

I don't get `GeneratedRgCronJob, platform generate com.***.core.customjalo.cronjob.RgCronJob`

so I can't extend or get exception "class is already defined"

try to

1. exclude `autocreate="true" generate="true"`
2. do impex for jaloclass

Comment: **1.** You should always post the version of SAP Commerce you are using **2.** From your screenshots, it seems your project (team) is generating a customjalo instead of jalo folder and I assume there is some customization to which and how artefacts are to be generated **3.** I think in the latest versions (e.g. 2205), SAP Commerce has stopped generating `GeneratedMyType`  as described [here](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/8c00066686691014a5a5d19875a1525b.html). I may be wrong as I have not been tracking the changes for more than 3 years.

Comment: Please validate my 3rd point (mentioned above) by installing v-2205. If my guess is correct, it's a shame that SAP has not updated the documentation. Until 2019, I used to raise such issues through experts.hybris.com administrators but I stopped contributing after it was merged into answers.sap.com.